# In Rails, how do I define a "_new_path"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, path, routes

I’m using Rails 4.  How do I define a “_new_path” in my routes.rb file?  I’m tryhin got create an admin area where an admin can create objects.  So I have this in my config/routes.rb file

```
  get 'admin/index'
  get 'admin/list'
  get 'admin/add'
  get 'admin/approve'
```

Then in my app/views/admin/_add.html.erb file, I have

```
<%= form_for @my_object do |f| %>
```

but when I visit my page, I get the error

```
undefined method `my_objects_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ffea5de2c80>:0x007ffea5dd9798>
Did you mean?  my_objects_new_path
```

I want the form to submit to the “create” method in my controller.  How do I set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this commande rake routes to show yours paths `rake routes`

```
admin_index GET  /admin/index(.:format)   admin#index
admin_list GET  /admin/list(.:format)    admin#list
admin_add GET  /admin/add(.:format)     admin#add
admin_approve GET  /admin/approve(.:format) admin#approve
```

after in app/views/admin/_add.html.erb file

```
<%= form_for admin_add_path do |f| %>
```